# Android Firebase build failed from Android Studio. Manual build from bash is working

Tags: android, firebase

I'm facing with following log errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkPrestagingDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$MetadataRegistrarNameRetriever found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$RegistrarNameRetriever found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentFactory found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.CycleDetector found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.CycleDetector$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.CycleDetector$ComponentNode found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.CycleDetector$Dep found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Dependency found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.DependencyCycleException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.DependencyException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.EventBus found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.EventBus$$Lambda$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Lazy found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer$RestrictedPublisher found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Event found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.EventHandler found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Publisher found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.events.Subscriber found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.firebase.inject.Provider found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.1.0)
```

I'm not using firebase.
I'm using implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning with "16.1.5" version
and
implementation "com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning: with "16.1.2" version

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: Yes.Two libraries used, among other dependencies, two different versions of firebase

Comment: Which mean you updated firebase lib not the ML kit one. Is it?

Comment: No it means that I excluded a version of firebase in an external library that I used and that contained a version that was misaligned with the rest of the app